# My simple "counter app" crashes when trying to move to another activity...why?

Tags: java, android-activity, crash

When trying to move to another activity the app crashes...

### logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{myact.julianhernandez.com.counterapp/myact.julianhernandez.com.counterapp.CounterDisplay}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:244)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3888)
        at myact.julianhernandez.com.counterapp.CounterDisplay.onCreate(CounterDisplay.java:31)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
```

### MainActivity.class Code

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button moveActivity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    moveActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.list1_button);

    moveActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent toCounter = new Intent(MainActivity.this , CounterDisplay.class);
            startActivity(toCounter);
        }
    });
```

### CounterDisplay.class Code

```
public class CounterDisplay extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView countView;
private Button addButton;
private Button subtractButton;
//int initialCount = 0;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_counter_display);

    countView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentCount);
    addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    subtractButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subtract);



    countView.setText(0);

    //increment counter by 1
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int currentCount;// = initialCount;
            for(currentCount=0;currentCount>=0;currentCount++){
                countView.setText(currentCount);
            }
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Why does this code crash when switching activities?

Comment: last loop looks like an infinite loop btw

Comment: and which line is 31th line of CounterDisplay class? it says resource not found.

Comment: @XiaweiZhang No it isn't. It is very likey, that it is wrong, but not infinite.

Comment: Why does it crash? String resource not found. It's right there in the text you provided.

Comment: @takendarkk Ok thanks...but what resource is it talking about, I didnt even mess with the strings.xml file (Sorry if this is an idiotic question but this is literally the first app im trying on my own without following a video).

Comment: @XiaweiZhang What do you suggest I change the loop to if I simply want the count to be incremented by 1 each time the button is pressed?

Comment: It's from line 31 of the onCreate method of the CounterDisplay class. Again, all just from reading the text you posted :) Did you read it at all or just panic because something went wrong?

Comment: @takendarkk I kind of just paniced and posted this. Thanks a lot though, you definitely taught me what to look for, I fixed the problem and it moves activities...it still crashes but for another reason now which I already diagnosed with the log...turns out i just had to open my eyes HAHAHA, thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Slow and steady friend. Errors will always happen, just use all the info you have.

Comment: @XiaweiZhang Actually I just realized Im kinda just complicating it, I dont need a for loop i can just add 1 to the variable (dont know why i didnt just do that in the first place), and im also going to have to convert the int to a string. I tend to over complicate things sometimes, its my first time trying on my own, thanks

Comment: @JulianHernandez take your time and be patient when writing code :)

Comment: countView.setText(String.valueOf(currentCount));

Answer (score 1):

Textview.setText(int) method takes a resource ID, not the text you are trying to display. Because there are no resource strings matching the ID you pass in (which is 0 on line 31), an exception gets thrown.

There are additional overloads of the setText() method that allow you to pass in a char[] if you don't want to use resource strings. View the documentation for more information. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html